# Numbers under "Epoch x/y .... " are unusually small during training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am using Tensorflow 2.3 to read 3 data files, which have rows and columns, to train a model. This is my sample code:

```
#Input data pipeline
input1 = tf.data.TextLineDataset("Inputs1.raw").skip(1)
input2 = tf.data.TextLineDataset("Inputs2.raw").skip(1)
output = tf.data.TextLineDataset("outcomes.csv").skip(1)
INPUT1=tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(input1, sep='\t'), out_type=tf.dtypes.float32)
INPUT2=tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(input2, sep='\t'), out_type=tf.dtypes.float32)
INPUTS=tf.concat([INPUT1, INPUT2], axis=0)
INPUT_OUTPUT = tf.data.Dataset.zip((INPUTS, output))
dataset=dataset.shuffle(128, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
dataset=dataset.repeat(3)
dataset = dataset.batch(128).cache()
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
next_element = iterator.get_next()
inputs_features=next_element[0][0]
output=tf.constant(tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(next_element[1], sep=","),out_type=tf.dtypes.float32).numpy()[:,2])

#Model Training
initializer = tensorflow.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
inputs = Input(shape=(2555922, ),name="inputs_features")
first_dense = Dense(16,kernel_initializer=initializer, )(inputs)
drop = Dropout(0.2)(first_dense)
out = Dense(1, )(drop)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00004,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=1e-07,amsgrad=False,name="Adam"), metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(inputs,output,verbose=1,epochs=10000)
```

My dataset has 400,000 samples and my batch size is 128 but, my numbers under "Epoch x/y .... " are 4/4 as you see:

```
Epoch 81/10000
4/4 [==============================] - 65s 16s/step - loss: 14.5471 - mse: 14.5471
Epoch 82/10000
4/4 [==============================] - 73s 18s/step - loss: 12.8519 - mse: 12.8519
Epoch 83/10000
4/4 [==============================] - 37s 9s/step - loss: 15.5236 - mse: 15.5236
Epoch 84/10000
4/4 [==============================] - 31s 8s/step - loss: 15.6709 - mse: 15.6709
Epoch 85/10000
```

Could you please tell me why I am getting 4/4 here despite the fact that dataset size/batch size is way more than 4? How can I solve the issue? I do no know what I need to do after calculating iterator and before model.fit.

Comment: You reinitialized `inputs = Input(shape=(2555922, ),name="inputs")` over the dataset slice.

Comment: + instead of `tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator` use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Iterator

Comment: @krenerd 
could you please post a sample code. After prefetch and before model.fit I do not know what I need to do. Documentation is also confusing

Answer (score 0):

You use `.fit` in a wrong way . Try `model.fit(dataset,verbose=1,epochs=10000)`

Comment: Thanks but I need to do some modifications to extract inputs and output from next_element. I can not feed dataset into model.fit directly. What shall I do?

Comment: You use ```inputs``` twice . ```model.fit``` 's first parameter is ```x```. Read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)

Comment: Could you please tell me how I have to reinitialize instead? I do not know what I have to do between iterator and model.fit. –

Comment: @hsn15051 ```inputs = Input(shape=(2555922, ),name="inputs_features")``` and ```model.fit(inputs,output,verbose=1,epochs=10000)```  . This is wrong ......

Comment: @hsn15051 ```model.fit``` 's first parameter is ```x``` and the second is ```y``` . Read the api document

Comment: Please, instead of posting code in the comments, edit & update (expand) you answer accordingly if you need to explain in more detail.

Comment: @DachuanZhao could you please post a sample code. After prefetch and before model.fit I do not know what I need to do. Documentation is also confusing.